# Con rod fastener's washers: tabbed or spring washers?

Tags: fastener, washers, connecting-rod

The engine I'm rebuilding (Skoda Estelle/120, 70's, RWD, rear mounted engine) has a mix of different washers in its con rod bolts: some were tabbed washers, other spring washers... two or three bolts didn't have one whatsoever!

The engine was working just fine, however as I'm rebuilding it to a better state the question arises: should I only use tabbed washers for the con rod nuts, or can I use spring washers instead?

The fasteners are M8 x 1.25...the torque is to be between 18 and 20 lbs.

EDIT:

- *Tabbed washer, from catalog:*

  [image: Tabbed washer]
- *Con rod nut, from catalog:*

  [image: Con rod nut]
- *Parts catalog exploded view*:

  [image: Parts catalog exploded assembly]

Comment: I'm not really sure why it would have washers in the first place. I would think spring washers would mess with the torque (not give a true reading).  I'm not really sure what a "tabbed" washer is (I believe it to be a language difference). Having anything other than a flat washer here would be foreign to me. If you could do this without washers, I think you'd be in better shape. Whatever you do, keep it consistent throughout. That would be my recommendation. M8 is a really small fastener for connecting rods I'd think! It seems to have lasted this long, I guess it will last a few more revs! :o)

Comment: Tabbed washers: those with "tabs" that once the fastened is tight you bend and hammer the tab against the bolt head/nut to avoid getting the fastener lose because rotational vibration. The original parts catalog shows them, Haynes manual doesn't...and the engine itself had a mix of washers. I need to replace the nuts, the originals are too clubbed, I would use new "regular/normal" nuts, the original have some kind of ring on the side that sits in the rod cap, like a built in separator or flat washer.

Comment: Gotcha ... I wouldn't use the tabbed ones at all. Also, use Locktite on the nut to keep it in place ... never go wrong with it to hold the nut on your fastener.

Comment: @Paulster2. Thanks sir. However, no Locktite in this part of the world. I need to find alternatives, ie, nail polish

Comment: Well, with that in mind, I'd go with tabbed over spring washers just because it should hold it better without distorting the torque readings.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the tabbed washers : they don't affect the torque reading as once the nut is torqued, they bend easily and just lock the nut into place. Loctite - if available - may not always be effective if the parts are not clean. Tabs work if the parts are clean or dirty.